# Is 'acronymise/ze' a word? Is it used only colloquially, if at all?

Tags: abbreviations, formality, is-it-a-word, acronyms, word-formation

I just sent a text to a friend, who didn't understand an acronym I used for a game:

> "Ah, I said it in a previous text so thought it was ok to **abbreviate**
>   it."

Though, since it was an acronym I had created, could I have used the word 'acronymise/ze' to be more specific?

I'm pretty sure it isn't a (formally used) word, but I wondered, as you often refer to acronyms specifically as acronyms, rather than abbreviations. Can you be more specific with a verb, too?

It sounds too odd to me, so I'm guessing generally no. But I wondered—so perhaps I'm wrong. Or half wrong.

Comment: Yes. However, "acronymize" and "abbreviate" aren't synonyms.

Comment: Why bother to *acronymize*? If I'm going to take such liberties, I might as well just *acronym* the text.

Answer (score 4):

[acronymize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acronymize)

Alternative forms

```
acronymise (UK)
```

Etymology

From acronym +‎ -ize
Verb

acronymize (third-person singular simple present acronymizes, present participle acronymizing, simple past and past participle acronymized) (transitive) ***To turn a phrase into an acronym.***

You'll not find it in many dictionaries, however, and I only got 4+K hits on Google. My guess is that it is still slang.

Comment: I was considering using it in present participle form to dictae my e-mail address, which would be stated something like this, Acronymizing, my e-mail address is oicurez2db8....instead of so many other words to steer the recipient to get it right over a landline, where texting isn't an option. But seems like it should be acronymizingly, ....

Answer (score 1):

I have just used it (with an 's' since I am from the British Isles) and therefore it is a word. This is exactly how language develops.

Regards - John, linguist and educational consultant.

Comment: Short and to the point. Great answer, John. Welcome to EL&U!

Comment: In regards to Johns comment above would it then be okay to use this word in my dissertation,
for e.g: 'Disease and infectious filth are a useful device for tracing back key anxieties within a society at a certain period. One that was rife, particularly in New York within the timeframe that American Psycho is set was the Human immunodeficiency virus infection and acquired immune deficiency syndrome, acrynomised to ‘AIDS’.'