# Is the suffix "-ize" particularly productive in the morphological domain of nouns ending in "-nym"?

Tags: suffixes, morphology, verbing, productive-affixes, morphological-domains

On a recent question asking [if *acronymize* is a word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142243/is-acronymise-ze-a-word-is-it-used-only-colloquially-if-at-all), a comment caught my attention:

> Why bother to *acronymize*? If I'm going to take such liberties, I might as well just *acronym* the text.

This really got me thinking. I am quite certain I've never used either verb. But I am just as certain that if I had to verb *acronym*, and do it quick, my brain would not so much as consider *to acronym*. There's just something about it that doesn't quite feel right. *To acronymize*, on the other hand, sounds perfectly natural. So not only would I go with the latter, but I'd do so without giving it a second thought. On complete autopilot. Instinctively.

Why would that be? That instinct has to come from *somewhere*.

My first and only guess right now is that *-nym* is the perpetrator here. That it outright attracts the *-ize* rather than the null morpheme. [Just like *-(o)log-* attracts *-ical* over *-ic*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6600/300), that kind of thing. But is that really true, or is there something else at work here?

And as a bonus question: are there other morphological domains in which *-ize* is especially productive? For a suffix that common, I suppose it's not too unlikely that someone actually went to the trouble of compiling a handy list of them all.

Comment: I would venture that stress patterns and pronunciation shift regularly when an -nym words get "ized". I've never heard acronymized but I imagine it would follow the same pattern as synonym/synonymize.

Comment: Hmmm. Google Books claims 796 instances of [pseudonymed](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pseudonymed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), as against 656 [pseudonymized](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pseudonymized%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (plus 241 [pseudonymised](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pseudonymised%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), presumably from lexically adventurous Brits). There are several hundred instances of *synonymed* too. Looks like we're in linguistic territory where people make things up as they go along.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between the suffixes -ize and -ify?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189530)

Answer (score 2):

Let's see here.
Your first question is why you would choose "-ize" as the N->V suffix for "acronym".
Wikipedia lists five V producing suffixes (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_verb-forming_suffixes):

- -en (Hard -> Harden) so Adj->V
- -fy (Can't think of a single example)
- -ify (Beauty -> Beautify) so N->V
- -ise (Alternative of -ize)
- -ize (Custom -> Customize) so N->V

Now, take a look at the list of verbs with "-ify", every root is one or two syllables. Furthermore, most of them seem to mean "to make as if [the root]".

On the other hand, (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ize#English) define "-ize" as "to make what is denoted by [the root]"

SO there are in fact only two N->V suffixes you could've chosen from, and "-ify" doesn't fit the bill, both in terms of meaning and prosody. So it makes perfect sense that you instinctively want to "acronymize" instead of "acronymify" (blegh).

I don't think, however, that it has to do with "-nym". You also see "realize" and "desensitize" and "misogynize" and "conceptualize" whose endings are all different. It seems more like the "-ize"/"-ify" distinction is based on length a little bit, meaning a little bit, and then maybe just custom. I'd have to look at word lists more in depth to figure out any real patter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You simplized the whole thing!